# Nonempty fibres of a map partition the domain

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I am trying to solve problem 2.5.1 in Artin's *Algebra*, the statement of which is:

> The nonempty fibres of a map form a partition of the domain.

I think my proof has all of the essential elements, but it seems a bit "messy" to me. I'd greatly appreciate some feedback on both the content and structure of it.

> Let $f: S \to T$ be a map of sets where $S,T \neq \emptyset$. I claim that
> $$ 
> S = \bigsqcup\limits_{t \in \text{Im}(f)} f^{-1} (\{t\}),
> $$
> i.e., that the fibres of $f$ form a partition $S$. Notice that, for each $t \in \text{Im}(t)$, there exists at least one preimage $s \in S$ under $f$ by definition, so $f^{-1} (\{t\}) \neq \emptyset$. By definition, the fibres of $f$ are subsets of $S$, so their disjoint union is likewise a subset of $S$. Now, as $f$ must map every element of $S$ to some element of $T$, denoted $f(s)$, we have $s \in f^{-1} (\{f(s)\})$, so $S$ is a subset of $\bigcup\limits_{t \in \text{Im}(f)} f^{-1} (\{t\})$. Finally, it suffices to show that if $t \neq t'$ in $T$, then $f^{-1} (\{t\}) \cap f^{-1} (\{t'\}) = \emptyset$. If $x \in f^{-1} (\{t\})$, then $f(x) = t$. But functions must map each element of their domain to a unique element of their codomain, so we have $f(x) \neq t'$ and hence $f(x) \neq t'$ and hence $x \not \in f^{-1} (\{t'\})$. By interchanging labels, we find that if $x \in f^{-1} (\{t'\})$, then $x \not \in f^{-1} (\{t\})$. So $S = \bigsqcup\limits_{t \in \text{Im}(f)} f^{-1} (\{t\})$, as required.

I saw the proof as taking three parts:

-Show that every fibre I wrote down was actually nonempty. This implies almost immediately that their union is a subset of $S$. (I skipped to disjoint union for this step, and I'm not certain it makes a difference.)
-Show that every element of $S$ is covered by at least one fibre.
-Show that distinct fibres don't overlap, so the union is disjoint.

I think I was able to show these things, but with much clutter.